# How to fix missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call (MapBox Scene Kit)

Tags: swift, swift4, mapbox, scenekit

I'm writing an app to view locations in AR using MapBox Scene kit. I keep getting the error "Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call" and no where seems to document the issue.

I know the code I have has worked in the past (August 2018) so I believe that the framework has been updated. If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

```
        if let terrainNode = terrainNode {
            terrainNode.scale = terrainNodeScale // Scale down map
            terrainNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -0.15, 0) // Place map slightly below clouds
            terrainNode.geometry?.materials = defaultMaterials() // Add default materials
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(terrainNode)

            terrainNode.fetchTerrainHeights(minWallHeight: 100.0, enableDynamicShadows: true, progress: { progress, total in
            }, completion: {_ in
                NSLog("Terrain load complete")
            })

            terrainNode.fetchTerrainTexture(type, progress: { progress, total in
                self.progressView?.progress = progress
                NSLog("Texture load complete")
                terrainNode.geometry?.materials[4].diffuse.contents = image
            })
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SthrN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very precise and tells you exactly what you need to do: add a `completion`  parameter to your `fetchTerrainTexture` call, like so:

```
terrainNode.fetchTerrainTexture(
    type, 
    progress: { progress, total in
        self.progressView?.progress = progress
        NSLog("Texture load complete")
        terrainNode.geometry?.materials[4].diffuse.contents = image 
    },
    completion: { image, fetchError in
        // whatever needs to be done on completion
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Do you have any idea why I get the error message `Extra argument 'zoom' in call`. I looked at all sceneKit documentation and it seems correct.

Comment: Since none of the code you've shown uses a `zoom` argument, this must be an entirely different issue, but again, the message is precise: You're pasing a `zoom` parameter to a method that does not  (or no longer) expect such a parameter.